# Mysql issue - ruby on rails + xampp on windows 7 (64bit)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have xampp 1.7.4(mysql version 5.5.8) installed on my windows 7 machine (64bit).
Now I want to work with Ruby on Rails. For that I have installed Railsinstaller (v2.2.3) from http://railsinstaller.org/en.

After installation, I checked Rails version and it seems to be version 4.1.1

Now the problem is that I can't setup mysql to work with ruby on rails.
I followed the instruction in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/getting_started.html to configure mysql database.

I wrote **$rails new blog -d mysql**
and it says "**ERROR: Failed to build gem native extention**" also "**An error occurred while installing mysql2 <0.3.16> and Bundler cannot continue**"

I looked for related articles with these issues and tried to fix, but never got success. I think it's mysql issue because xampp is already installed. Is it right?

Any ideas to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4041559/1297435

Comment: You do not necessarily need MySQL. You can also use built in SQLite which works just fine for 99% of use cases. You can try https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2 Windows guide ;) it installs "gem install mysql2" not "mysql".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I want to use current installed mysql with xampp.